# SVG is not showing on my localhost Apache v3.3.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I tried to use a  Search Icon in my header section,h but it is not shown . I tried everything but still no chance !

I added AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz I tried AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz and a few other lines I found on the net but still no chance . Can someone tell me what exactly should I do now ? My other SVGs are shown however and It is very strange !

```css
.SearchIcon{
    background-image: url(icons/search-solid.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    filter: invert(32%) sepia(24%) saturate(298%) hue-rotate(132deg) brightness(98%) contrast(89%);
    
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><i class="SearchIcon"></i></a>
```

AND HERE IS MY SVG FILE :

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="search" class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using it as a background-image, you can just insert the svg-tag into your body:

```css
#my-svg{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #2c676f;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="search" class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" id="my-svg"><path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
  </body>

</html>
```

With CSS it's possible to change the size or color as shown.

Comment: You're answer actually worked ! I used chrome and there is something wrong with my Chrome that is why it is not showing